# How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to remove time portion of date time or probably have the date in following format in object form not in the form of string.

06/26/2014 00:00:00:000

I can not use any string conversion methods as I need the date in object form.

I tried first converting the date to string, remove the time specific date from it, but it adds 12:00:00 AM as soon as I convert it to DateTime object back again.

Comment: Sorry, read that wrong. You say `06/26/2014 00:00:00:000` is OK, too? Great, because with a time of `12:00:00 AM` it's just that. And as all the answers showed, there is no need for string manipualtion.

Answer (score 9):

You can't create a DateTime object without a time in it. It always has some time in it.

If you want to output it without a time portion, you can use a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/az4se3k1(v=vs.100).aspx) to do so:

```
date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/az4se3k1(v=vs.100).aspx)
[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

As others have said, you can access `date.Date` to get a value with any specific time information omitted, but that will still have a time of 00:00 AM.

Comment: OP wants a `DateTime`: _"not in the form of string"_. I guess [Adil's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27561540/284240) is what he''s looking for.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well then, OP is out of luck unless they want to use something outside the .NET core. But it sounds like an X->Y problem to me. The question is _why_ they want this.

Comment: I guess OP is confused because the DateTime appears to have `12:00:00 AM` at the end but that is just how it is displayed wherever he looks at it. Since he doesn't want a string he has reached the goal  with `DateTime.Date`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I imagine so. I don't see how Adil's answer is any different from mine, aside from being posted 2 minutes later and providing fewer references.

Comment: @TimSchmelter _"As others have said, you can access date.Date to get a value with any specific time information omitted, but that will still have a time of 00:00 AM."_

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property of DateTime object to get only day.

```
DateTime dateOnly = date1.Date;
```

If you want string of Date from the DateTime object then use the ToString method by providing it the format. You can read more about custom date format in this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string strDate =  date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: {07/09/15 12:00:00 AM}

Answer (score 2):

> I need to remove time portion of date time...

It is impossible. You *can't* have a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) instance without time information. For example, you can't have a `DateTime` instance as just `06/26/2014` or just `00:00:00:000` only.

If you wanna get only date part of your instance, you can use [`DateTime.Date` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.date.aspx).

> Gets the **date** component of this instance.

But still, this `.Date` property assign it's time part to midnight.

Remember, a `DateTime` doesn't have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. The concept of *format* only applies when you want to show it as a `string`.

In a representation part, you *have to* use string representation as;

```
yourDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: does it(yourDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);) remove the time part?

Comment: @r.hamd When you use `ToString` method, you generate a _textual_ (aka string) representation of your `DateTime`. That means, it is _not_ a `DateTime` anymore. It is a `string`. Sure you can get _only_ date part with generating it's string representaiton but you _can't_ have a `DateTime` instance _without_ time part. It is _really_ important to understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

The date variable will contain the date, the time part will be 00:00:00.

Comment: {07/09/15 12:00:00 AM}