# How can I change DateTime to exclude timestamp in this situation?

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller

In this team ASP.NET MVC project, there's a `JPStudent` index view with the lambda expression:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JPStartDate)
```

`JPStartDate` is a `DateTime` property of the `JPStudent` model. The `Index` view returns a time stamp with the date, but I need it to display only day, month and year.

I know the common answer is to convert the `DateTime` to string in order to do this. At first, I was going to convert it to string and add it as another property to the list, since I need to maintain the same lambda expression which returns `item.JPStartDate`  (I'm not supposed to mess with that expression, as per team rules). I would've then switched out the `item.JPStartDate` in the expression for the new property. However, I get errors in my model file when I try to add the date string as a new property in the properties list.

The `JPStudentsController` sets:

```
jPStudent.JPStartDate = DateTime.Now;
```

So I tried my string conversion to `ddmmyy` here, and got

> Cannot implicitly convert string to DateTime

errors. I'm a little stumped here. I need to extract only the day, month and year but without messing with the way the `Index` view is set up to return the date property to the view.

Does anyone have any suggestions in this particular situation? I may be missing some simple way of doing it that I'm just not thinking of right now. If anyone has any suggestions for isolating day, month and year from `DateTime`, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561530/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only

Comment: Thank you, JohnB.  I'm having a look right now.

Comment: Can you use DisplayTemplates? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365633/what-is-the-html-displayfor-syntax-for

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114874/html-displayfor-dateformat-mm-dd-yyyy

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the year, month and day from a DateTime? Is that correct? If so, you can just use the Day, Month and Year properties:

```
        var jpStartDate = DateTime.Now;
        var day = jpStartDate.Day;
        var month = jpStartDate.Month;
        var year = jpStartDate.Year;
```

Answer (score 1):

By this way you will change the value:
    DateTime jpStartDate = DateTime.Now;

```
DateTime reduced = new DateTime(jpStartDate.Year, jpStartDate.Month, jpStartDate.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

or

```
reduced = jpStartDate.Date;
```

It depends if you want to change only visualisation or also a value.